# automatically updated records in database

Tags: jpa, jpql

Before I summit the front entry data (with JSF/PrimeFaces), I had to check if existing name record. view scope bean like this :

```
public void updateProfileListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) { 
  if(supplierService.isExistSupplierName(supplier.getName(), true))  return;
//  else saveDate();
```

}

and database check code like this :

```
userDatabase.createQuery("select c from Supplier c where c.name = :name")
        .setParameter("name", name)
        .getResultList();
```

It is just regular query sql for checking if existing name, but it is still to update the new data from front entry, May I know what happened?

Comment: The `WHERE` is by default case sensitive. So a name of "foo" is not the same as a name of "Foo". Did you take this into account? By the way, for the action method, I'd just put an `UNIQUE` constraint on the column and catch the constraint violation. By the way, this is not a JSF problem at all. It has already successfully delivered the submitted data to you. Anything beyond that step is not JSF's responsibility. So I fixed the tags :)

Answer (score 0):

BalusC's rigth!

Now, if you want find olny 1 supplier you may try add other data validation in where clause( well, i dont know your business logic :D ).
But, you really want resultList I think better use 'like'

select c from Supplier c where c.name **like** ...